# MS Graph API metadata field update

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api, metadata

I'm trying to update the custom metadata in my drive item. Based on the documentation of the MS Graph API, it says we should tangle with FieldValueSet class. Hence I do the following.

```
public void updateMetadata() {
    DriveItem driveItem = graphClient.sites(getSiteIdByName("sps-test")).lists(
            getListFromSite("sps-test", "Shared Documents").id)
            .drive().items().byId("mysupersecurid").buildRequest().expand("listItem").get();

    System.out.println(driveItem.getRawObject());

    FieldValueSet valueSet = driveItem.listItem.fields;
    valueSet.additionalDataManager().put("Name", new JsonPrimitive("Hello"));
    JsonObject rawObject = valueSet.getRawObject();


    FieldValueSet result = graphClient.sites(getSiteIdByName("sps-test")).lists(
            getListFromSite("sps-test", "Shared Documents").id)
            .items("mysupersecureid").fields().buildRequest().patch(valueSet);

    System.out.println(result.getRawObject());
}
```

This should conclude the process but I'm getting invalid request exception in the last call with .patch method.
I get the following error:

```
   {
  "error": {
    "code": "invalidRequest",
    "message": "Field \u0027id\u0027 is not recognized",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2021-02-01T14:19:15",
      "request-id": "46e67786-b021-43cd-a48e-080c35d475e6",
      "client-request-id": "f0c59880-df5e-4259-877d-0c65cb7b1aee"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would create a new `FieldValueSet` and not using the `FieldValueSet` from the response.

You are using the `FieldValueSet` returned in the previous response which contains `id` (which is a unique identifier) and adding/updating value in it. Then you are sending `FieldValueSet` in the patch request by `id` cannot be updated.

```
FieldValueSet valueSet = new FieldValueSet();
valueSet.additionalDataManager().put("Name", new JsonPrimitive("Hello"));
```

Comment: That is correct. The same goes for any other objects you want to update using Graph Api